# Get meta description in schema Product description

Tags: magento-1.8, php, seo

In the header I have the following code for meta description.

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription()) ?>" />
```

I am trying to get this description as my schema product description as follows in the view.pthml file

```
<meta itemprop="description" name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription()) ?>" />
```

However "Description" it shows up as a blank on the google rich snippets tool.

When I enclose

```
<meta itemprop="description" name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription()) ?>" />
```

with a `<span itemscope itemtype="Http://Schema.Org/Product" >` it shows up, but of course breaks the other product itemtype thats on the page.

So how do I get the description in the header to show as my schema product description?

Note: the default meta description is not used (blank) a extension called creare SEO creates the meta description based on attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(Mage::registry('current_product')){
Mage::registry('current_product')->getDescription();
}
```

instead of `$this->getDescription() ;`

Hi,In product page $this->getDescription() function logic depend on 
below logic

```
$description = $product->getMetaDescription();
            if ($description) {
                $headBlock->setDescription( ($description) );
            } else {
                $headBlock->setDescription(Mage::helper('core/string')->substr($product->getDescription(), 0, 255));
            }
```

this Code is exiting on file`app/code/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php`
.If you have any issue change logic here.it maay you data issue

Just put code in view.phtml

```
<?php 
 $description='';
 $description = $_product->getMetaDescription();
            if ($_product->getMetaDescription()) {
               $description=$_product->getMetaDescription();
            } else {
                $description=Mage::helper('core/string')->substr($_product->getDescription(), 0, 255);
            }
?>
<meta itemprop="description" name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($description) ?>" />
```

**after**

```
  <?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
```

**Last resolution:**

```
<?php $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head'); echo $description=$headBlock->getDescription(); ?>" />
```

Comment: so it will be like this 

<meta itemprop="description" name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars if(Mage::registry('current_product')){
Mage::registry('current_product')->getDescription();} ?>" />

Comment: yes.also put else conditions

Comment: it is only works for product page

Comment: sorry what will be the actual code?

this is what I have

<meta itemprop="description" name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars if(Mage::registry('current_product')){
Mage::registry('current_product')->getDescription();} ?>" />

Comment: the view.phtml file i'm talking about is 

app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

Comment: are you put  this meta data is view.phtml file?

Comment: I have put this in the view.phtml file

<meta itemprop="description" name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars if(Mage::registry('current_product')){
Mage::registry('current_product')->getDescription();} ?>" />

Comment: then try this  $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head'); $description=$headBlock->getDescription();

Comment: WHere do I put that, I'm sorry my knowledge of PHP is limited, so you will have to give me more detail :-)

Comment: I tried this 

<meta itemprop="description" name="description" content="<?php echo $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head'); $description=$headBlock->getDescription(); ?>" />

The description is still blank when I use the google rich snippet tool (GRST), its not getting the description from the header.

Comment: suro.are want this description from magento products  which filed?

Comment: Yes the header description which appears in 

<meta name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription()) ?>" />

Fails to show when I try this in the view.phtml file

<meta itemprop="description" content="<?php echo $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head'); $description=$headBlock->getDescription(); ?>" />

On the front end view source it shows as 

<meta itemprop="description" content="" >

Comment: I want the <meta name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription()) ?>" />

From the head.phtml file to show in the view.phtml file

Comment: please check <?php $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head'); echo $description=$headBlock->getDescription(); ?>" />

Comment: @user2240778... it will better idea to paste your code in head.phtml(app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourmodule/template/page/html/head.phtml)

Comment: This works!

<?php $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head'); echo $description=$headBlock->getDescription(); ?>" />

You're a genius! Thank you so very very much, I really appreciate it :-)